# Using Python to find security holes - "A file has a security hole if it has read, write, or execute permissions for the group and world users"

Tags: python, python-2.7, permissions

I am tasked with writing a Python 2.7 script to find "security holes" in the script's working directory.

I found and modified a script that checks for files with 777 and 775 permissions:

```
import os
i=1
for filename in os.listdir('.')
    path=os.path.join('.', filename)
    if os.path.exists(path):
        if(os.stat(path).st_mode & 0777) == 0775:
            print "==== Problem File " + str(i) + ": ===="
            print os.path.abspath(os.path.join('.', filename)) + "\n"
            i=i+1
```

But then I reread my assignment instructions and it says *"A security hole means that the file has read, write, or execute permissions for the group and world users."*

I'm unsure of what this means. So a file with, say, `-rw-r--r--` is considered to have a security hole because it has read rights for both `group` and `world`? Or `-rwxr----x` has a security hole because `group` has read rights and `world` has execute rights?

If that's true, why is this considered a security hole? How could I modify the script to account for those permissions too?

Comment: A security hole for, say, a `.pem` file might be that it's readable by anyone except the owner. A security hole for a script might be that it's executable by anyone except the owner. It's pretty dependent on context.

Comment: I'd read that as meaning everything *except* 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, or 700 is a security hole, i.e. if any one *other* than the owner can do *anything* with the file.

Comment: ^ Okay, I'm starting to believe it's that, thank you. So then they should have said "... permissions for the group and/or world users."